# Trailing dot trouble while saving MVC 5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this model item to modify and save in MVC 5.
(.NET Framework 4.6.1)

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "wrapperViews" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>EQUIPMENT - @ViewBag.EQP_ID</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OPERATIONID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TYPE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TYPE,
                       new SelectList(Model.EquipmentTypes, "CodeType", "DescriptionType"),"", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TYPE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div style="width:500px;margin-top:15px">
                <div style="width:120px; float:left;margin-left:30px">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn" />
                </div>
                <div style="width:120px; float:left;">

                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Back to the list", "Index", "Equipment", new { id = Model.OPERATIONID }, new AjaxOptions()
                    {
                        OnSuccess = "OpenEquipment"
                    })

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is that entity field to modify contains dot in the name, like that:

```
  http://localhost:62396/controllername/Edit/SUPREP.ABL
```

When I submit the form, it comes error

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:62396/controller/Edit/SUPREP.ABL
Physical Path      C:\projectname\controller\Edit\SUPREP.ABL
```

I tried anything I could but I didn't solved my trouble.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just Solved. Need to add to RouteConfig.cs the following line:

```
routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
```

And everything works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your URL. IIS thinks that you're requesting for a file with extension ".ABL". You can simply add a trailing / to make it act like a route.

e.g.: http://localhost:62396/controllername/Edit/SUPREP.ABL/

Also make sure you've enabled double escaping by adding this to web.config :

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
</security>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do but I don't know how to intercept the Url and add the the trailing. I have just submit button. How do I do ?

Comment: @Riddick, you also need to enable double escaping. I've updated my answer, have a look.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know how to add the trailing.

Comment: Here I am again. I just solved. The solution is to add to RouteConfig.cs the line   routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true; and even security tag you told me is not necessary. Anyway, thank you for helping me find solution.